# Toggling css in knockout.js for changing select list width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, selectlist, jquery-templates

I am using Knockout.js with jQuery tmpl plugin. The template I have defined has a few select lists. I need to expand the width of the select items (on IE 8) when a select list is clicked (to accomodate the longest element in the list). I was thinking of toggling the css class when a user clicks on the select list to achieve this but am not sure how to go about it. Here is what I have so far:

```
//CSS classes
<style>
    .bigclass
    {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .normalclass
    {
        width: auto;
    }
</style>

// Call makeBig javascript method on mouseover.
<script id='criteriaRowTemplate' type='text/html'>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 23%"><select style="width: 100%" data-bind='event: { mouseover: makeBig, mouseout: makeNormal}, options: criteriaData, optionsText: "Text", optionsCaption: "--Select--", value: SearchCriterion' /></td>
    </tr>
</script>

var CriteriaLine = function() {
    this.SearchCriterion = ko.observable();

    //Control comes to this method. Not sure though if the element captured is correct.
    makeBig = function(element) { 
        $(element).addClass("bigclass")
    };
    makeNormal = function(element) { 
        $(element).addClass("normalclass")
    };
};
```

So my questions are:

1. How do we pass the select list to the makeBig javascript function? I believe I need to change the following syntax in my code:
   data-bind='event: { mouseover: makeBig, mouseout: makeNormal
2. How do we add the class to the passed select list. I have added the code but it's not working, maybe because element doesn't have a value.
3. Alternatively, is there any other approach to ensure that the user sees the full text of the dropdown in IE 8?

Comment: can't you just bind to click and blur?

Comment: I can bind to click. e.g. In the above code, I am able to call expandOptions method upon clicking. But don't know how to change the css class after binding.

Comment: if using jquery,  $(element).addClass("bigclass")

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, but this is the fiddle I'm working on, in coffeescript... http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/j5Awx/

Comment: Thanks @Keith. The coffeescript version works. How can I make it work with knockout and jquery?

Comment: nah, if you look, it doesn't work properly,  if you drop down a list, and then move somewhere else, it's all a bit weird.  I don't know enough of how the dropdowns work to hook it properly,  on the fiddle, up the top, you can click a button to see the javascript

Comment: coffeescript is just a language that creates javascript,   the coffeescript is using knockout and jquery also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom binding to add a CSS class to the element on hovering:
http://jsfiddle.net/BL9zt/

Note that it subscribes to the IE specific `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event, so you also have to reference jQuery which simulates those events in the other browsers.

Another, knockout-independent approach is described here:
http://www.getharvest.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/select_box_demo.html